# Phase subscript for supercritical reagent?

Tags: phase, notation

When writing a chemical reaction, one can use subscripts to denote the phase of a reagent, e.g. $\ce{SiO2 (s)}$, $\ce{H2O (l)}$, $\ce{F2 (g)}$ or $\ce{Na^+ (aq)}$. However, I need to write a reaction involving a reagent that is above its critical point. What is the subscript for a supercritical reagent?

Comment: I don't think there are simple subscripts for more exotic phases.

Comment: @Mithoron How should I notate it then?

Comment: Just a note on the notation itself: the phases should not be set as subscripts. It is still very common, but the recommendations are now to put it in line, I.e. $\ce{H2O(l)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted if not standardised notation is Sc or sc - I've seen both.  Capital "S" followed by a lower case "c", e. g.  ScCO2 is the one I've seen most often in chemistry related papers.
EDIT - apologies, this is a prefix and not a subscript. Hopefully you get the point

Comment: Could you add example? I doubt it should be written the way you did.

Comment: Try http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/supercritical/scwater.html or http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403900019171?via%3Dihub for examples used by supercritical fluid practioners

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper answer is (g), the same as a gas.  After all, the critical point of hydrogen is -240 °C and 2.24 atm.  But no one refers to a compressed cylinder of hydrogen gas as "supercritical hydrogen".  It's just a compressed gas.

After all, supercritical fluids meet the formal definition of a gas: they have neither a defined shape nor a defined volume.  (Liquids have no defined shape but do have a defined volume.)  The critical transition is the loss of stability of the condensed (liquid) phase; in contrast, both before and after the critical point there is a a well-defined gas phase.

Usually when people say "supercritical" they mean "above the critical point, but not by much" or something similar.  It's a not-well-defined term. I'd avoid using a special abbreviation for it, since supercritical fluids really are just gases.